# Zoom in/out plates into fullscreen by using css or javascript

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-animations, react-transition-group

Does anyone know a library (preferably react) that could help in achieving such effect in zoom in/out when clicking on plate https://work.co/?

Answer (score 0):

I think to achieve such effects you need to use css3 transform and transition property. 
Also you can use react to fetch data add events on div.

Comment: that is definitely true, I'd just like to have some more high-level tool or library helping to achieve those transitions.